# Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK Error on Generate Wrapper parameter is incorrect

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm-2011

When trying to run "Generate Wrapper" on my entities I receive the following error message:  The parameter is incorrect( Exception from HRESULT :0x80070057 E_INVALIDARG))

I'm using on-premises CRM 2011, developing in VS 2010

I've seen the problem listed [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/a817cfc8-eef5-4a5f-adb2-7f670b8beff4) but no solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem.Removing all solution folders fixed it.

Looks like bug in Dev toolkit :/

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I created a new solution and generated the wrapper for this new one. Then I copied the generated file to the "corrupted" solution... it´s kind of ... but it did work.
It´s not nice to have two solutions for one project but it is the only way I could generate the wrapper.